# How to express exponential Chebychev's inequality

Tags: probability, inequality

I learned that Markov's inequality ([source](https://www.math.uni-frankfurt.de/%7Eismi/wakolbinger/teaching/StofI1920/1920Vorlesung7b_k.pdf), page 31) can be expressed in terms of the exponential, i.e.,

\begin{align}
P(X \geq b) \leq \frac{E[\exp(tX)]}{\exp(tb))}.
\end{align}

Is there an exponential upper bound for Chebyshev's inequality,

\begin{align}
P(|X-E[X]| \geq b) \leq \frac{\operatorname{Var}[X]}{b^2}?
\end{align}

I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Exponential_moment) Wikipedia article, but I am confused by the form. I need the left hand side to be $P(|X-E[X]| \geq t)$, not the one shown in the Wiki section. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $ (X-\mu)^2 > 0$
According to Markov’s inequality
$$Pr((X-\mu)^2>k^2) < \frac{E[exp(t(X-\mu)^2]}{k^2}$$
$$Pr(|X-\mu|>k) < e^{{\mu}^2 t} \frac{E[e^{{X}^2 t -2\mu Xt}]}{k^2}$$